# How can I display an array of objects inside a object in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to make a mock news react app and I am using newsapi's node package. This returns a response that has an array of objects inside one object. I set the state to the response of the newsapi function and when I log it to the console I get the object. I just can't display it on my site because I don't know how to display a state of objects inside a array.

**Here is my App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
const NewsAPI = require("newsapi");
const newsapi = new NewsAPI("APIKEY");

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { articles: {} };

    newsapi.v2
      .topHeadlines({
        category: "business",
        language: "en",
        country: "us"
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ articles: { response } });
        console.log(this.state.articles.response.articles[2]);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let article = this.state.articles;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div
            style={{ marginLeft: "23em", width: "75%", paddingBottom: "20px" }}
          >
            <Paper>
              <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <p style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
                  <b />
                </p>
                <br />
              </div>
              <p>
                {article.map(articles => (
                  <p>{articles.name}</p>
                ))}
              </p>
              <br />
              <Divider />
            </Paper>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", paddingTop: "20px" }} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I currently get the error that map isn't a function.

**Response from API:**

[image]

// Edited: Changed articles from array to object.

// Thanks to everyone... devserkan's answer helped the most and I can now move on with my project!

Comment: Can you share the API response?

Comment: Also, you are defining your `articles` state as an array but then in your `setState` you are setting it in an object.

Comment: Also added my response from the API.

Comment: You had it right the first time, keep `articles` as an array in your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as told you should keep your `articles` state as an array in your state since it is an array in your response. Then you can map it easily. Here is a working example. I am faking API response here but you can use it for your situation.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: [],
  }

  response = {
    status: "ok",
    totalResults: 20,
    articles: [
      { author: "foo", title: "bar" },
      { author: "fizz", title: "buzz" },
    ]
  }

  getArticles = () =>
    new Promise( resolve =>
      setTimeout( () => resolve(this.response)), 500)

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getArticles()
      .then(response => this.setState({articles: response.articles}))
  }

  render() {
    const {articles} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          articles.map( article => (
            <div>
            <p>Author: {article.author}</p>
            <p>Title: {article.title}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

For your situation, just look at my example and set your `articles` state as an empty array. Then use your newsApi call in your `componentDidMount` method. I'm providing your fixed code here but can't be sure it works since I can't test it.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { articles: [] };
  }

  getNews = () =>
    newsapi.v2
      .topHeadlines({
        category: "business",
        language: "en",
        country: "us"
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ articles: response.articles });
      });

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNews();
  }

  render() {
    let articles = this.state.articles;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div
            style={{ marginLeft: "23em", width: "75%", paddingBottom: "20px" }}
          >
            <Paper>
              <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <p style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
                  <b />
                </p>
                <br />
              </div>
              <p>
                {articles.map(article => (
                  <p>{article.author}</p>
                ))}
              </p>
              <br />
              <Divider />
            </Paper>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", paddingTop: "20px" }} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What have I changed?

- Change `articles` shape in your state.
- Create a function to get news: getNews.
- In this function get the news and set the articles like this: `this.setState({ articles: response.articles })`
- Add componentDidMount and invoke the created function.
- In render method change `article` name to `articles` since this is more consistent. Also change `articles` to `article` in your map.
- There is no `name` in an article, so I've changed it with `author`.

Comment: How can I pass the response of the newsapi function into mount?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you still get an error please add your code somewhere like codesandbox.io. So we can play with it.

Comment: Thank you... I have been learning MERN for about two weeks now and actually doing it yourself is very complex and confusing.

Comment: You are welcome. One week is a short time to grasp all MERN. Take your time, after some time you understand that how easy and nice React is. But grasping whole MERN needs some serious time.

Comment: Just component based coding compared to simple mingw or xampp is pretty interesting so far.

Comment: I can't compare to PHP or anything else since I don't know them if you mean those, but sure React is a great library not a language :)

Comment: I used to use the WAMP stack a lot but single page applications in either MEAN or MERN is the future I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your articles as an object instead of an array.
Then, when you try to "map" your articles, you get an error because object doesn't have a map function.

You can fix this by setting your articles object in your state to be an array:

```
this.setState({ articles: response.articles });
```

Note I removed curly braces around the response to prevent creating a new object

Comment: It is still saying map isn't a function.

Comment: And I want to print a list of titles. I can't figure out how to call an array and choose a value inside in object in the array.

Answer (score -1):

map work only for arrays, use for in or foreach

```
let articles_name = [];
for (var index in  this.state.articles) {articles_name.push(<p>this.state.articles[index].name</p>)}




   {article.map(articles => <p>{articles.name}</p>)}   can be replaced by  {articles_name}
```

Comment: So how would I display my array of objects inside of the object?

Comment: i have editet, i had this problem in the past and i think i solved it so, this is one thing i hate on js compared to php

Comment: It is not so complex to do this as you said.  Actually it is very easy. So, no need to hate anything.

Comment: @devserkan well this is one of stupid things on js, i can map and array but not an object(or array with keys) and this solution was more for other simlair problems(supply stuff over axios u will fight with this)

Comment: btw on J. Borga  position i would do a console.log(article) and check if its really a array and not an object on level higher

Comment: First of all for OP's question, problem is not mapping objects. Second, mapping objects can be done in various ways. Let's stop arguing over this please. I respect your opinions but can't agree to them.

Comment: its okay, the -1 shows all, anyway i would really look what the console.log shows, in the end it shows still an object

Comment: Yes, I donwvoted and do to anyone who says "I hate JS because you can't map objects". Please, if you state some horrible opinions here bare with its consequences.

Comment: i sayd i hate this handling(which is stupid) not the language, im out...